# ERROR: Setup iteration failed: Unidentified error, check logs in portal / compute

Tags: python, automl, azure-machine-learning-service

Getting error when trying to run the autoML through training cluster. But it is running successfully via the local run.

Comment: A reproducible example would be helpful. I recommend starting with getting one of these notebooks working, then porting it to work for your scenario.
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning

Answer (score 0):

the namespace for AutoMLStep changed recently, if you are using <1.0.76 the namespace would be "from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLStep", for >=1.0.76, you'll want to use "from azureml.train.automl.runtime import AutoMLStep" instead.

Please upgrade bellow package
pip install azureml-train-automl-runtime==1.0.85.4

[image: working code in attached screeshot]